# ML support on Grafana

Tags: grafana

I have deployed the free version of Grafana on Kubernetes : https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/kubernetes/

I see in Grafana docs that Grafana ML is just available on cloud https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/machine-learning/. Is it available for free on an on prem install ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grafana Machine Learning was [introduced](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/10/13/introducing-grafana-machine-learning-for-grafana-cloud-with-metrics-forecasting/) only as a part of Grafana Cloud solution.

AFAIK, there were no additional announcements regarding Grafana Machine Learning on-premise.